# mark overlapping events in fullcalender with cell background color

Tags: events, background, fullcalendar, cell, overlapping

I'm using fullcalendar to show different dates of different tours as an event.
At some point people have the choice of joining a different tour, because the location of the event is overlapping for some days. That means, for example, two events at the same day

Is it possible to change the background color of the cell to point it out ?

For example, on 13-14. October the events are overlapping. Therefor a different background color like yellow would make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a line to the fullcalendar.css

```
.fc-state-intersect
{
    background: green;
    display:none;
}
```

Then you will have to programatically add this class to your JSON reply so it looks like this more or less

```
... {"title":"Intersect",
     "start":"2011-05-04T00:00:00",
     "end":"2011-05-04T00:00:00",
     "allDay":true,
      "className":".fc-state-intersect" <-- 
...
```

Like discussed in our comments, you will have to generate a separate feed or maybe even inject into your existing feeds these events on your calculated intersected dates.

The display:none is the so that the actual event does not show- we only use that so it applies the colour to the cells it overlays

Adding these events should be pretty straight forward. 
But the hard work will have to be done server side calculating where to insert these hidden events

There is no built in function in FullCalendar to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Well, I do not need to highlight an event, I need to highlight the cell background color of the table, where the events are showing up. Two events: one event has the color red, the other event has the color green. Because they taking place on the same day, I want to highlight the cell background in yellow to point out, that these events are overlapping and the people can take certain actions. cheers
alexandra

Comment: Right! I tried to show you an example and i realised what the problem is. IF you have a long event that intersects- you want the intersecting day to show (end of event 1 and start of event 2) or possibly all intersecting days..... I gave you code to highlight the entire duration of both events possibly in 2 different colours. So... This changes everything... Really good question. I will have to think about it. This sounds like a plugin.

Comment: The only other way is to use some jQuery. And in my head i know how to do it.. but i need to write it down and experiment. Hope my efforts will pay off ;)

Comment: What about adding an event at all relevant intersecting days (not all intersecting days may be relevant for highlighting) to mark the days, where the special cell background color should be applied to. The event itself can be transparent and invisible. Maybe only the tooltip will pop-up...

Comment: Yea you can do that too - but then you have to calculate server side when these dates happen and import them like an extra feed- which is feasible. I suspect you would have to apply a "display:none; background: green;" to that event so it marks the location.

Comment: PS If you find my posts helpful please upvote me (press up button) on the post or comment. This is a great reward for me especially that i am the only one trying to help you here. You can/but dont have to assign a correct answer when you feel it appropriate. Thanks

Comment: Hey, many thanks for your efforts ! Adding extra feeds for the intersecting days should be possible, but I still have no clue how this will change the table-cell background color for these events. Found something interesting in google code: "dayRender trigger for modifying a day" looks promising...